# MySQL Optimization - MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high, but still recommending increases

Tags: mysql

I have a cPanel/CentOS 6.5 VM with 12 GB RAM.

I ran the MySQLTuner script, and followed the recommendations that they gave, but it's still recommending increases, while telling me that MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high.

My current config in my my.cnf file is:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
query_cache_size=32M
innodb_file_per_table=1
open_files_limit=6740
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
tmpdir=/mysqltmp
group_concat_max_len=102400

tmp_table_size=64M
max_connections=500
interactive_timeout=30
wait_timeout=30
thread_cache_size = 16
thread_cache_size=16
table_cache=2000
join_buffer_size=32M
query_cache_limit=512M
key_buffer_size=128M
max_heap_table_size=32M
```

I restarted MySQL a short while ago to apply my most recent changes.

When I run the script, this is what I get:

```
      >>  MySQLTuner 1.3.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.36-cll
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 551M (Tables: 467)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 49M (Tables: 908)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 37)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 17

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 2h 6m 33s (379K q [49.933 qps], 2K conn, TX: 390M, RX: 115M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 51% / 49%
[--] Total buffers: 336.0M global + 34.6M per thread (500 max threads)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 17.2G (148% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/379K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 1% (5/500)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/125.7M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (4M cached / 1K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 58.0% (145K cached / 251K selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 892777
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 10K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 3054
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 29% (6K on disk / 20K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (5 created / 2K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 95% (1K open / 1K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 14% (999/6K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (261K immediate / 261K locks)
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/49.1M
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (> 32M)
    join_buffer_size (> 32.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    tmp_table_size (> 64M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 32M)
```

If I increase those variables, I'll be even higher with memory usage.

Does anyone have any recommendations with what to do now?

EDIT: Here are the results 14 hours after the last MySQL restart:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.3.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.36-cll
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 552M (Tables: 467)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 49M (Tables: 908)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 37)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 21

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 14h 2m 3s (1M q [20.830 qps], 9K conn, TX: 1B, RX: 281M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 56% / 44%
[--] Total buffers: 336.0M global + 34.6M per thread (500 max threads)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 17.2G (148% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/1M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 1% (5/500)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/125.9M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (15M cached / 1K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 76.3% (625K cached / 820K selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 250933
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 35K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 8623
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 31% (26K on disk / 82K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (5 created / 9K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 58% (2K open / 3K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 17% (1K/6K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (469K immediate / 469K locks)
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/49.1M
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (> 32M)
    join_buffer_size (> 32.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    tmp_table_size (> 64M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 32M)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your config file as per below suggestion and check-

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
 
query_cache_size=32M
innodb_file_per_table 
open_files_limit=6740 -- only 14% is using, so you can reduce it to 1500, to use your RAM in better way.
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
tmpdir=/mysqltmp
group_concat_max_len=102400

tmp_table_size=64M
max_connections=500 -- as per your error report, only 3 are in use so you can set it to 100. As it will use memory un-neccesorily.
interactive_timeout=30
wait_timeout=30
thread_cache_size = 16
table_cache=2000
join_buffer_size=32M
query_cache_limit=512M -- It should be less then query_cache_size, so keep it max. 10M
key_buffer_size=128M --  keep it 25% of your total RAM but not greater than 3 GB for Myisam engine, so in your case set is 3G.
max_heap_table_size=32M -- your server will use total memory for temp tables which ever will be lesser out of tmp_table_size, max_
```

Comment: I don't think their values are accurate since the server is running for just 2 hours.

Comment: you can intially set open_files_limit=3000 (it is sufficent) and max_connections=250 and check your problem. Further you can set them later as per your requirement and as per mysql report. Other values seems at par, so you can try.

Comment: Thanks for the response and detailed info!
Would it help if I posted updated results from the script?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Working in implementing your settings now, looks like the last one got cut off - any idea what that was supposed to say?
Thanks!

Comment: Plz check last variable remarks: your server will use total memory for temp tables which ever will be lesser out of tmp_table_size, max_heap_table_size and space in tmp partition. As per my suggestion these 3 should be at least 100M to take care heavy queries and to take care any alteration of big table. Currently 31% tmp table is creating on disk which will kill the performance, so increase it to 500M if still you get it in your error log.

Comment: Please note that `table_cache` was renamed to `table_open_cache` in MySQL 5.1.3. For versions >= 5.1.3 this will block mysql server from starting up, as `table_cache` will be an unknown option.

Answer (score 5):

Does your server really need 500 multiple connections ? If it doesn't, you can change this setting to a proper value.

The script basically multiplies **max_connections** with some settings. A thread needs to allocate some memory for itself (1 connection = 1 thread). Some settings that are used per thread: thread_stack, net_buffer_length, ...

More information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-use.html

Comment: I believe the script recommended increasing that earlier, and I already adjusted that, but I can try lowering it, and see if that helps.
Thanks for the info!

Comment: No problem. If you want to monitor how many multiple connections the server have used since the instance started: show variables like 'Max_used_connections'

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question. However, recently, I faced this issue personally as well and came across this post. The answer didn't help me, but question was relevant to what I faced. Upon further analysis and digging around. I found a nice script that helped in identify the memory usage in clear terms at https://tech.labelleassiette.com/how-to-reduce-the-memory-usage-of-mysql-61ea7d1a9bd. Copy/Pasting the script here for ease of reference in future.

```
#!/bin/sh
# you might want to add some user authentication here
mysql -u root -p  -e "show variables; show status" | awk '
{
VAR[$1]=$2
}
END {
MAX_CONN = VAR["max_connections"]
MAX_USED_CONN = VAR["Max_used_connections"]
BASE_MEM=VAR["key_buffer_size"] + VAR["query_cache_size"] + VAR["innodb_buffer_pool_size"] + VAR["innodb_additional_mem_pool_size"] + VAR["innodb_log_buffer_size"]
MEM_PER_CONN=VAR["read_buffer_size"] + VAR["read_rnd_buffer_size"] + VAR["sort_buffer_size"] + VAR["join_buffer_size"] + VAR["binlog_cache_size"] + VAR["thread_stack"] + VAR["tmp_table_size"]
MEM_TOTAL_MIN=BASE_MEM + MEM_PER_CONN*MAX_USED_CONN
MEM_TOTAL_MAX=BASE_MEM + MEM_PER_CONN*MAX_CONN
printf "+------------------------------------------+--------------------+\n"
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "key_buffer_size", VAR["key_buffer_size"]/1048576
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "query_cache_size", VAR["query_cache_size"]/1048576
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "innodb_buffer_pool_size", VAR["innodb_buffer_pool_size"]/1048576
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "innodb_additional_mem_pool_size", VAR["innodb_additional_mem_pool_size"]/1048576
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "innodb_log_buffer_size", VAR["innodb_log_buffer_size"]/1048576
printf "+------------------------------------------+--------------------+\n"
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "BASE MEMORY", BASE_MEM/1048576
printf "+------------------------------------------+--------------------+\n"
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "sort_buffer_size", VAR["sort_buffer_size"]/1048576
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "read_buffer_size", VAR["read_buffer_size"]/1048576
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "read_rnd_buffer_size", VAR["read_rnd_buffer_size"]/1048576
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "join_buffer_size", VAR["join_buffer_size"]/1048576
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "thread_stack", VAR["thread_stack"]/1048576
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "binlog_cache_size", VAR["binlog_cache_size"]/1048576
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "tmp_table_size", VAR["tmp_table_size"]/1048576
printf "+------------------------------------------+--------------------+\n"
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "MEMORY PER CONNECTION", MEM_PER_CONN/1048576
printf "+------------------------------------------+--------------------+\n"
printf "| %40s | %18d |\n", "Max_used_connections", MAX_USED_CONN
printf "| %40s | %18d |\n", "max_connections", MAX_CONN
printf "+------------------------------------------+--------------------+\n"
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "TOTAL (MIN)", MEM_TOTAL_MIN/1048576
printf "| %40s | %15.3f MB |\n", "TOTAL (MAX)", MEM_TOTAL_MAX/1048576
printf "+------------------------------------------+--------------------+\n"
}'
```

Using this script, it cleared for me the memory requirements. Once you understand how the usage of memory is happening, it is clear what to tune and where to tune.